# How to filter on joined tables where a column is not equal to a value?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables namely departments and Employees. I want department-name whose employees are not a programmer.

Here is my [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be34c6b19b6c5d3236e5cbc04d12ab02) of the problem.

I want output as HR but it shows both HR and IT. I have tried this but it's not working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dept_name 
FROM Departments INNER JOIN Employees 
     ON not Emp_Skill='Programmer' AND Deptid = Employees.EDept_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT Dept_name 
FROM departments 
WHERE Deptid NOT IN (SELECT edept_id FROM Employees WHERE emp_skill ='Programmer')
```

This will select only departments that doesn't have any employees that are programmers.

Comment: Thank you! it works, but can you please explain to me it's working.

Comment: @PrajaktaKale, the subquery will give you the department ids with programmer employees. so will only select those dept that are not IN the subquery